# Can i set two different kind of actions on one form?

Tags: html, drupal-6, forms

Hey guys
i was making one web sites.
 in that, there is one page on which i have one form, so in that
i want two thing done on same data.
1) it should store in the database 
 2) that form data should also to be send on one email account.

i know i can do this if i use "mail" function of php and on that same php file, i can store that. but i don't want my mail goes to spam [ if i use mail function then my mails are going as spam in users email. ]

So is there any way that i can do two different action on same form data.
and what is there any other way to do the same.

btw i am using drupal-6.

thanks in advance.

---

Nitz.

**EDIT:**
I don't want my mails go as spam. 
 i am sending mail using this kind of code....

```
<form action="http://www.bluehost.com/bluemail" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
Name : <input type="text" readonly value= "me"><br>
EMail ID : <input type="text" id="email" name="mailfrom"><br>
Query : <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="19"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="sendtoemail" value="admin@example.com"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Thank You"></form>
```

now by this way my mails are not going as spam.
so now what i want is....
i want to send mails and also want to store information in database also.

Comment: The mail going into the spam folder has nothing to do with your server functions, it has to do with the content of the email.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more?
First you say you want to store and mail, then you say you don't want to mail. I pressume you only want to mail in certain cases or so?
If you want to submit the form twice, you could do that with javascript.

Comment: Maybe you could just ask the client to put the server email address into their address book so the emails won`t go to spam? Depends of course what email service they use, but this usually works for online ones.

Comment: @dain....usually user don't like to do this kind of stuff or may they don't even know this kind of things...so i can't do that.....

Comment: @Redlab....may be u can understand by my edited question....sorry i am very bad at explaining point...so now may be u can understand, that what i want.....

Comment: @animuson.....i don't know yet about that "content of email" things...but i know that if i use php mail function then mail going into spam folder......

Comment: @Nitz: But the PHP mailing function is not what's causing it to go into their spam folder. Spam filters look at emails based on their length and keywords within the content etc to determine whether it is "spam" or not. The only way to prevent that is to reword your emails in a way that won't cause them to get filtered by the recipient. There is *nothing else* you can do other than changing the messages that are sent.

Comment: @animuson....thanks for this great information....
i think, i have to change some design or something or flow....

Answer (score 0):

it is most likely due to the smtp that is used by php mail or the senders address. Try with another mailer library where you can customize more (e.g. use another smtp server). see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872639/good-php-email-library